# How to speed up magento site?

Tags: magento, web, pagespeed

My site is www.suresafety.com which is in magento 1.9.2.0. It was working fine from last 1.5 years, but from last 2 months, It is too much slow. There are 1400 products in it.

It's speed in speed insight was 83 before 1 year. Now It is 39 which is not good for our e-commerece.

I have done all this below steps:

1)  Combine CSS and JS Files
•   In the Magento Admin, go to System > Configuration > Developer.
•   Under “Javascript Settings”, change “Merge Javascript Files” to YES.
•   Under “CSS Settings”, change “Merge CSS Files” to YES.
•   Clear the cache.

2)  Enable Flat Catalog

•   In the Magento Admin, go to System > Configuration > Catalog.
•   Under “Frontend”, change “Use Flat Catalog Category” to YES.
•   Under “Frontend”, change “Use Flat Catalog Product” to YES. (optional)
•   Clear the cache.

3)  Make sure the section with the deflate compression rules is not commented to enable the default compression rules.

```
 ## enable apache served files compression
 ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

# Insert filter on all content
###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
#Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

4)  Add expiration time for images,js,css (.htcaccess)

```
##for image test
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On<br/>
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"<br/>
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"<br/>
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"<br/>
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"<br/>
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"<br/>
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"<br/>
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"<br/>
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"<br/>
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"<br/>
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"<br/>
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"<br/>
</IfModule><br/>
```

5)  Cpanel -> Optimize Website -> tic on 2nd option(Compress all content)

6)  Download optimized images,css,js from page insights(bottom)

7)  Replace with the old one.

Comment: Check your website in https://tools.pingdom.com/. I have checked your website, It will take 50 seconds for loading, landing page size 2.4mb, lot of unwanted redirection and missing image file path.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the things you've already applied but you can also apply following points:-

a- please Install following extensions:-

https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc

https://github.com/tinify/magento1-plugin

b- http://magento2x.com/optimize-magento-database-by-cleaning-log/

c-Please improve your server configuration e.g- set Memory limit to 1024M (Optional)

d- Install & use Memcache/varnish cache (Optional)

e- You can take dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug to Figure Out Why Your Website Is Running Slow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the below url for speed optimization :

https://www.keycdn.com/blog/speed-up-magento/

below for database optimization :

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

ALTER TABLE `log_url` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `log_url_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `log_visitor` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `log_visitor_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `report_viewed_product_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;